# How to display Schedule object related list using <apex:relatedList> on a Visualforce page?

Tags: standard-objects, related-list

I have created a Visual Force Page for the Opportunity Line Item and I would like to display the related list object (i.e. Schedule) in the Visual Force Page.How to call it using the `<apex:relatedlist>` tag.

Can we use `<apex:form >` and `<apex:relatedlist>`  in the same page.When i tried using the `<apex:relatedlist>` tag ,it does not allow the `<apex:form>`.

Any Suggestions.

Comment: What are you referring to, when you are writing 'tag'?

Comment: This looks like a follow up question to http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/51712/how-to-display-a-related-list-in-a-visualforce-page

Comment: @AlexanderJohannes:I'm trying it as <apex:relatedlist list = "OpportunityLineItemSchedule" >

Comment: @nikkey please use backticks to format `inline code`. Otherwise it will not be visible. I have edited your question.